# accessing threads by name

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to implement some basic threading in my script and I need to check whether the thread already exist or not, I've found how to set names but cannot figure out how to use is_alive function by name

```
class History(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        #do some stuff

for i in range(10):
    t = History
    t.setName("name%s"%i))
    t().start()
```

how can I check later is thread name5 is alive or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is_alive` method [does not take any arguments](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive). You don't use `is_alive` by name. Instead, just call `t.is_alive()`
to check if the thread `t` is alive.

```
class History(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def run(self):
        #do some stuff
    
threads=[History(name="name%s"%i) for i in range(10)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

while threads[5].is_alive():
    ...
```

PS. The docs say the [name attribute](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name),

> ... is a string used for identification purposes only. It has **no
> semantics**. **Multiple threads may be given the same name**.

so don't rely on the name as a definitive means of identification.